# Modification to merge sort to sort using Insertion sort and then merge normally

Tags: java, sorting, mergesort

Given this merge sort code I am not sure how to modify the code to sort with insertion sort so that we divide the data length n into k intervals with insertion sort and then merge these sorted k intervals with the normal merge sort method.
Here is my merge sort code
public class hw4class1 extends Sorter{

```
public static void printArray(int[] array) {
            if (array.length <= 100) {
                for(int i=0; i < array.length; ++i) {
                    System.out.print(array[i]+" "); // print out values
                }
                System.out.println();
            } else {
                System.out.println("array too large to print ("+array.length+" elements).");
            }

        }

        public void sort(int[] values) {
        System.out.print("call to "+this.getClass().getName()+" with ");
            printArray(values);
            if (values==null || values.length <=1) { // check for termination condition
                System.out.print("returning from "+this.getClass().getName()+" with ");
                printArray(values);
                return;
            } else {
                int middle = values.length/2; // divide array into two arrays of half size
                int[] left = new int[middle];
                for (int i=0; i<middle; i++) {
                    left[i] = values[i];
                }
                int[] right = new int[values.length-middle];
                for (int i=0; i<values.length-middle; i++) {
                    right[i] = values[middle+i];
                }
                sort(left); // recursively call sorting function on each smaller arry
                sort(right);

                int l=0, r=0; // combine sorted arrays
                for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
                    if (r>=right.length || (l<left.length && left[l]<right[r])) {
                        values[i]=left[l];
                        l++;
                    } else {
                        values[i]=right[r];
                        r++;
                    }
                }
                System.out.print("returning from "+this.getClass().getName()+" with ");
            printArray(values);
                return;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hint: Mergesort is recursive. What should happen if the array is shorter than n/k, versus longer?

Comment: What is the specific problem that you're facing?

Comment: Isn't there exist more interesting codding rather than a torment of sorting algorithms?

Comment: I want to replace this part of the code int middle = values.length/2; // divide array into two arrays of half size
                int[] left = new int[middle];
                for (int i=0; i<middle; i++) {
                    left[i] = values[i];
                }
                int[] right = new int[values.length-middle];
                for (int i=0; i<values.length-middle; i++) {
                    right[i] = values[middle+i];
                }
                sort(left); // recursively call sorting function on each smaller arry
                sort(right);